# How can I clean a string of a range of price connected by a dash(-) using Regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, data-cleaning

I want to clean a string of range of price `'GBP 10,000,000 – GBP 15,000,000'` and remove the currency `GBP` and replace the dash(-) with a comma(,) using Regex in Python.
The output I want is `(10000000,15000000)`.

This is what I tried:
`re.sub('[GBP,/s-]','', text)` which produces the output `' 10000000 –  15000000'`
I also would like to get rid of the leading and trailing whitespaces while replacing the dash(-) with a comma(,) to produce the output of a tuple `(10000000,15000000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.sub` with a callback function we can try:

```py
inp = "GBP 10,000,000 – GBP 15,000,000"
output = re.sub(r'[A-Z]{3} (\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*) – [A-Z]{3} (\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)', lambda m: '(' + m.group(1).replace(',', '') + ',' + m.group(2).replace(',', '') + ')', inp)
print(output)  # (10000000,15000000)
```

If you want an actual list/tuple of matches, then I suggest using `re.findall`:

```py
inp = "GBP 10,000,000 – GBP 15,000,000"
output = [x.replace(',', '') for x in re.findall(r'[A-Z]{3} (\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)', inp)]
print(output)  # ['10000000', '15000000']
```

Comment: You have any open source suggestions where I can learn regex for such tasks?